# Pull row data into modal window

Tags: php, mysql, html-table, edit

I have a mysql query within a PHP function:

```
 $sql_json = "SELECT * FROM mytable";
```

I am displaying the returned data into a table grid. The first row has an Edit button that once the user clicks on it, it opens a modal window. It should transfer the data from that row into the bootstrap modal window.

```
 echo "<tr><td>
<a class=\"btn btn-primary btn-mini\" data-toggle=\"modal\" href=\"#myEditModal\" data-project-id=\"" .$Row['pk_tId']. "\" \">Delete/Edit</a></td>";
```

Now I am trying to get `$Row['pk_tId']` into the modal window here:

```
 <div class="modal hide fade" id="myEditModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelleby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
 <div class="modal-header">
 <div class="modal-body">
 <form class="well-small" action="edit.php" method="POST" id="modalForm" name="modalForm">
 <input type="text" id="group" name="group" value="<?php echo $selection[mygroup]; ?>" />  
 <input type="submit" id="modal-form-submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary" href="#" value="Update" />
 </form>
 </div>
 </div>
```

Once I am able to get the `pk_tId` in the modal window, I should be able to perform a query to retrieve the data from the table.

I know this can be done with just PHP.

Please help.

******************** Update *****************

```
 $sql_json = "SELECT * FROM restable";
 $QueryResult = @mysql_query($sql_json) or die (mysql_error());
 echo "<table class='table table-striped table-bordered table-hover'>\n";
 while(($Row = mysql_fetch_assoc($QueryResult)) !== FALSE) {
 echo "<tr><td>
            <a class=\"btn btn-primary btn-mini\" data-toggle=\"modal\" 
            href=\"#myEditModal\" data=\"edit.php?id=\"".$Row['pk_tId']."\">Delete/Edit</a></td>";
 echo "<td>{$Row[resgroup]}</td>";
            echo "<td>{$Row[mytype]}</td>";
            echo "<td>{$Row[myservice]}</td>";
            echo "<td>{$Row[mydescription]}</td></tr>\n";
 };
            echo "</table>\n";
```

I think this is what you're asking for.  Please let me know what else you need.

Comment: missing a closing </div> tag. Please disregard.

Comment: where the problem you are getting? are you not getting value of $Row['pk_tid'] ? Its not clear in your question..

Comment: I am trying to pull $Row['pk_tId'] into the modal window.

Comment: Once I get that into the modal window, I think I can run a query based off the pk_tId variable.

Comment: can you show me , where you are fetching the rowset from query execution ?

Comment: I think this is what you're asking for:

     $sql_json = "SELECT * FROM restable";
     $QueryResult = @mysql_query($sql_json) or die (mysql_error());
     echo "<table class='table table-striped table-bordered table-hover'>\n";
     echo "<tr><td>
    <a class=\"btn btn-primary btn-mini\" data-toggle=\"modal\" 
    href=\"#myEditModal\" data=\"edit.php?id=\"".$Row['pk_tId']."\">Delete/Edit</a></td>";

Comment: Sorry, I was trying to put in the stackoverflow code view. let me try again.

Comment: I just added the query statement above.